# Javascript: Removing an object from array by checking it's attribute

Tags: javascript, json, performance, node.js

I might have written a pretty confusing title but my question is rather simple.

I'm looking for an efficient way to remove an item from an array. But my array is full objects that has been **stringified** (I'm writing my app on Node.js and I'm using **JSON.stringify** method). So my array is like this;

```
"{\"userID\":\"15\",
  \"possibleFollowers\":[
      {\"followerID\":\"201\",\"friends\":716},
      {\"followerID\":\"202\",\"friends\":11887},
      {\"followerID\":\"203\",\"friends\":11887}],
  \"name\":\"John\",
  \"lon\":\"Doe\"}"
```

My question is on Javascript(or Node). If I wanted to remove the from possibleFollowers with "followerID: 202", how would I be able to do that **efficiently**?

Comment: do you want to remove from JSON string or Javascript object ?

Comment: @Diode the object from the possible folllowers. I mean if it is `"possibleFollowers\":[
      {\"followerID\":\"201\",\"friends\":716},
      {\"followerID\":\"202\",\"friends\":11887},
      {\"followerID\":\"203\",\"friends\":11887}],` after the removal it should look like this;

Comment: `"possibleFollowers\":[
      {\"followerID\":\"201\",\"friends\":716},
      {\"followerID\":\"202\",\"friends\":11887}
      ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var string = "…";

var obj = JSON.parse(string);
obj.possibleFollowers = obj.possibleFollowers.filter(function(fol) {
    return fol.followerID != "202";
});
string = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: Beware of IE support though; IE >= 9 .. for node.js it shouldn't matter i guess :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = "{\"userID\":\"15\",\"possibleFollowers\":[{\"followerID\":\"201\",\"friends\":716},{\"followerID\":\"202\",\"friends\":11887},{\"followerID\":\"203\",\"friends\":11887}],\"name\":\"John\",\"lon\":\"Doe\"}";

var dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
dataObject.possibleFollowers = dataObject.possibleFollowers.filter(function(follower) {
    return !(follower.followerID == "202");
});
data = JSON.stringify(dataObject);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I haven't tried yet but looks just fine. However I was wondering, does your method and the well suggest **splice** method have a huge difference in terms of efficiency?

Comment: I was going to comment on the dangers of modifying an array while looping over it by index, and then the answer changed to use `filter`, which is what I was going to suggest! +1

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the splice method is used to delete an array element by index.

see :

http://www.roseindia.net/java/javascript-array/javascript-array-remove-index.shtml

Comment: Seen, searched but could not adopt to my problem. Yet thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: An additionally I would like to search for the object, **then** delete it.

Answer (score -1):

try just to delete it by using "delete"

```
for (var i in possibleFollowers) {
    if (possibleFollowers[i]['followerId'] == '216') {
        delete possibleFollowers[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: That will create a `null` entry in its place.